# GDB for debugging Linux device drivers

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, driver

I am new to using GDB debugger. I am following the link http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/01/understanding-a-kernel-oops/
I am using the same code and the same `Makefile`. Syslogd is running and `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` is set to `y`. But, I am still not successful. When I open the `.ko` file with GDB I get the message

> No debugging symbols found

and when I use the `list*` command, I get

> No symbol table found.

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output from `file oops.ko` (or whatever the .ko file is called)?

Comment: when I insmod oops.ko i get the output "killed" , when I do dmesg I get the kernel oops message

Comment: Please execute the command `file whatever_the_name_is.ko`.  It will tell if debugging symbols are present in the file or not.

Comment: It tells no debugging symbols found. I have already tried that. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably one of the quirks of building drivers out of tree. Using

CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=1 make

when you build your driver gets you the debug symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `-g` option while compiling the modules. This option should generate debugging symbols.
Cannot say exactly why your flag 'CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO' is not working.

Comment: can you copy paste your Makefile here.

Comment: I am using the same makefile given in the link http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/01/understanding-a-kernel-oops/

Comment: but there is no `-g` option in the makefile given in the link. you have to do it by yourself.

Comment: while compiling I have compiled make CFLAGS=-g . Will this not suffice? I have also tried "$(MAKE) -C $(-g) $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules" in the make file. This also didn't help