# debugging Device driver using GDB

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I'm new to device drivers in Linux. And my first day task is to debug driver using GDB in Linux.

- I need to debug some XYZ (PCIe device driver supports ethernet) device driver to know about the flow and what is going on device's registers and all.

I have installed the driver with patch file and **insmod** command.

**The device is working properly**. But *am not getting any solution to debug the device driver*.

All I know is that how to debug C program using GDB in Linux(fedora20). I got one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112685/gdb-for-debugging-linux-device-drivers)  similar to my Problem but from that also I have not got any knowledge.

Can anybody please share your thoughts that **how can I start from scratch**. 
I am very specific to learn about Debugging device drivers in Linux. Especially that **init** or **probe** function inside my driver I need to know the flow.

Comment: What kind of device are you coding your Linux driver for? Please **edit your question** to improve it, if possible show some [MCVE] (or at least give a link to your code).

Answer (score 4):

The [`gdb` debugger is useful](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) to debug [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) application level programs (since it uses [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)).

For kernel code, things are different. Consider [using `kgdb`](https://kgdb.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) (I don't know the details). You might also add [debug prints](https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing) ....

I recommend at least reading more about operating systems, e.g. [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable), and reading something about Linux programming (perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf), and also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and related stuff). Don't dare coding Linux [loadable kernel modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module) without good familiarity with Linux programming (in user-land). See also [kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/).

BTW, you should prefer writing user-land code than kernel modules. A very simple rule of thumb is to avoid writing kernel code when possible.

Comment: kernel modules are inserted into the kernel, so is kernel code.

Comment: you mean that my device driver has some kernel modules so it has been inserted into the kernel .. Using KGDB I need to try debugging my device driver right? I don't know about device driver so asking this kind of questions need a lot of assistance

Comment: You need to spend several weeks in reading much more, before typing a single line of kernel code.

Comment: 3 days is simply not enough. You probably need at least 3 weeks, and perhaps 3 months. You could add various print statments in that module. You probably won't find any step by step procedure. What will happen to you if you fail debugging that kernel module in 3 days?

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, you may need to understand basics of device driver and kernel in linux. Subsequently focus as per the type of driver in-hand. You also need to understand the functionality (specification / manual / datasheet) of the device you are working on.

The very basic approach for debugging can be using printk. Normally there will be debug logs that can be enabled through compilation flags. If it is present, enable it so that it can give important pointers else you might need to add it on your own.

Start with verification of driver registration and verification of loading of your driver (static or loadable module as per your requirement). Check whether it is getting listed as part of sysfs or proc as applicable. Check whether probe is successful and subsequently the appropriate read/write/open/close/other calls as per your driver / device functionality.

The dmesg shall be very helpfull for viewing the kernel messages. There are also tools like kdb, LTT, strace that can be useful as per the scenario.